# how the null value '\0' assign in the exacted \n index?

Tags: c, char, newline, c-strings, fgets

```
printf("enter destination file name to print : ");
    fgets(target_file, sizeof(target_file), stdin);
    target_file[strcspn(target_file, "\n")] = '\0'
    if(target_file == NULL){
        printf("enter any key to exit ....!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    writting_file = fopen(target_file, "w");

    if(writting_file == NULL){
        printf("error to open the file\n");
        printf("please enter any key to EXIT.......!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
;
```

**
target_file[strcspn(target_file, "\n")] = '\0'
**

how that change in the exact index?

Comment: Do you know what `strcspn()` does?

Comment: When you do `fgets(target_file, ...)` you need to provide `target_file` to be not `NULL`. If so, what sense does it make to test `if(target_file == NULL){ ... }` ...?

Comment: Welcome to SO. That code does not make sense: `if(target_file == NULL)` EIther `target_file` is an array, then you don't need to check for `NULL` (which is too late anyway after you already used it before). Or it is a pointer, then `sizeof(target_file)` will result in wrong value.

Comment: Read the documentation of [`strcspn`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/?kw=strcspn). It's explained there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this error was accurate by using of before scanf statement. that statement add a new line in the end of the line so, can modifiy the scanf to skip the newline character.

`scanf("%d*c",a);`

Answer (score 2):

```
fgets(target_file, sizeof(target_file), stdin);
target_file[strcspn(target_file, "\n")] = '\0'
```

This code will not compile due to the missing semicolon at the end. Let’s assume the semicolon is added.

If `fgets` is successful, it puts a string of characters in `target_file`. Note this code is defective because it fails to get the return value of `fgets`—`fgets` may leave `target_file` indeterminate or unchanged if it encounters an error or end-of-file before reading any characters, in which case it returns a null pointer.

Suppose `fgets` does succeed, `target_file` contains a string, which means it contains zero or more characters followed by a null character. Also, if `fgets` read a new-line character, it is the last character in the string, just before the null character. If `fgets` filled the available space before reading a new-line character, there is no new-line character in `target_file`.

`strcspn(target_file, "\n")` examines `target_file` to see how many characters at its beginning do not contain any characters from `"\n"`. If there is a newline character at index *n* in the array, then `strcspn` returns *n* because none of the characters from 0 to *n*−1 are a newline character. (`fgets` never returns a string with more than one newline character because it stops when it sees a newline character.) If there is no newline character in the array, then `strcspn` returns the length of the string, because it stops at the terminating null character.

Thus, the return from `strcspn` is either the index of the newline character (if one is in the array) or of the terminating null character (if there is no newline character).

Then `target_file[strcspn(target_file, "\n")] = '\0'`; sets this element in the array to a null character. So, if it is a newline character, it is changed to a null character, and the string is shorter and no longer includes the newline character. If it is a null character, there is no effect from assigning a null character to that element.

```
if(target_file == NULL)
```

This is useless code. If `target_file` is an array, it cannot be a null pointer. If `target_file` is a pointer (including a function parameter declared as an array but automatically adjusted to be a pointer), then it its use in `fgets(target_file, sizeof(target_file), stdin);` was a mistake for two reasons:

- `fgets` should not be passed a null pointer, so the `target_file == NULL` would need to be before the `fgets` call.
- `sizeof(target_file)` would give the size of the pointer, but what is needed there is the number of characters available at the place where the pointer points.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this sequence of statements

```
target_file[strcspn(target_file, "\n")] = '\0'
if(target_file == NULL){
    printf("enter any key to exit ....!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

does not make great sense. `target_file`  can not be a null pointer except initially before these statements it was already a null pointer. But if it is a pointer to a dynamically allocated array and is not a null pointer then using the operator `sizeof`  in the preceding statement

```
fgets(target_file, sizeof(target_file), stdin);
```

again is invalid. It makes sense to use the `sizeof` operator here if `target_file` is declared as a character array not as a pointer.

Instead you could write for example

```
if ( fgets(target_file, sizeof(target_file), stdin) == NULL )
{
    printf("enter any key to exit ....!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
target_file[strcspn(target_file, "\n")] = '\0';
```

As for the function `strcspn` then firstly bear in mind that the function `fgets` can append to the read string the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter and that you need to remove from the string and according to the function descriiption (the C Standard, 7.24.5.3 The strcspn function)

> 2 The strcspn function computes the length of the maximum initial
> segment of the string pointed to by s1 which consists entirely of
> characters not from the string pointed to by s2.

So either the function returns the length of a string before the new line character `'\n'` and thus you can change it to the zero terminating character '`\0'` excluding the new line character from the string or it returns the length of the whole string if the new line character is absent and setting the zero-terminating character (the value of the length is equal to the position of the terminating zero character in the string) to zero-terminating character keeps the string as is.

Comment: it's work. can you explain more i could not understand?

Comment: i use without if condition that skip the input line why?

Comment: @yokeshwaran It seems you did not use a loop. In loop you need to have a condition (the of statement) to determine that there are no more records. That is you expect only one input and you provided the input.

Comment: i sorry i have little confusion can you check this code?

Comment: Before I use getchar() without while loop it works, but i don't know hows it work

Comment: @yokeshwaran The call of getchar removes the new line character from the input buffer. Otherwise the next call of fgets reads an empty string that contains only that new line character.

Comment: i have exact answer why input skip in this line.